# Update JMenuItem via ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jmenuitem

I am trying to create a JMenuItem that is disabled by default, but a method can be called to enable it.  Just for the moment whilst I'm testing out my code, I want the method to be called when I click on another menu item. I have had a look at the documentation for JMenuItem, but I'm pretty new to Java and I'm having trouble finding exactly what I need.  I've tried using the updateUI() command, but I that hasn't worked, so I'm totally stuck.  Thanks in advance for any help :)

This is what I have so far:

```
public class initialScreen extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    Dimension screenSize = new Dimension(800,600);
    JMenuItem runE, newP;

    public initialScreen(){
        super("Experiment Control Suite");
        setSize(screenSize);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenuItem newP = new JMenuItem("New");
        newP.addActionListener(this);

        runE = new JMenuItem("Run");
        runE.setEnabled(false);
        runE.addActionListener(this);

        JMenu exp = new JMenu("Experiment");
        exp.add(runE);      

        JMenu par = new JMenu("Participant");
        par.add(newP);
        bar.add(exp);
        bar.add(par);
        setJMenuBar(bar);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void enableRun(){
        runE.setEnabled(true);
        runE.updateUI();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == newP) {
            enableRun();  
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == runE) {
            System.out.println("run has been clicked");
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method `enableRun` is never invoked because of the following line:

```
JMenuItem newP = new JMenuItem("New");
```

Instead, refactor it as such,

```
newP = new JMenuItem("New");
```

Now, the field will be correctly initialized and registered as an `ActionListener`. And thus, when checking the source, `enableRun` will be invoked and the menu item will be enabled.

Note that in this case, `updateUI` is completely unnecessary (I suggest you read the javadoc to learn its purpose).

Comment: Aha!  Glad it was a silly mistake rather than a fundamental misunderstanding!  Thank you :)